# C++ CLI NotifyIcon Show Balloon

Tags: c++-cli, notifyicon, balloon

C++/CLR Visual Studio

I am using a NotifyIcon which is initialized and is showed with the correct icon and text when I launch my application.
But I want to display a Balloon to the user. 
This is however not showing up.

```
notIcon->BalloonTipText = "Test";
notIcon->BalloonTipTitle = "Test";
notIcon->BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon::Info;
notIcon->ShowBalloonTip(10000);
```

I have this code on a button and when I click the button it does go to this I checked with breakpoints.
Nothing is showing and I get no errors/warnings.

I also added a messagebox and breakpoint at the BalloonTipShown method of the control but it never hits it.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There a boss override switch to tell Windows to *never* display a balloon tip.  You probably have it turned on.  Google "windows disable balloon tips" or ask at superuser.com

Comment: Alright I'll check that

Comment: Yeah I had it indeed disabled, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had it disabled in windows, my mistake.